# How do I open a specific folder with a file?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm trying to create an intent to open a folder with a file, but I still can't get access to it. When downloading, I save the file to the Downloads+"MyDirectory" folder, for example:

```
val destinationFolder: File = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS+"/MyDirectory//${FILE_NAME}")

request = DownloadManager.Request(url)
request.setAllowedOverRoaming(false)
.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED)
.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,"/MyDirectory//${FILE_NAME}")
.setDestinationUri(Uri.fromFile(destinationFolder))
```

And I'm trying to open it like this

```
  var path = context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS+"/MyDirectory//")
  val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
  intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
  intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(path), DocumentsContract.Document.MIME_TYPE_DIR)
  application.startActivity(intent)
```

And when I launch the application, a new folder is created, but the downloads folder opens, not my new folder. Do I want a new folder with my file to open when the intent is triggered, and not the downloads folder? How do I do this knowing the path to this folder?

Comment: `setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,"/MyDirectory//${FILE_NAME}")` AND `context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS+"/MyDirectory//")` do not match. Pretty different directories. Please tell which Android version on used device.

Comment: All has nothing to do with downloading. You could just have started telling that you created a file in that folder.

Comment: Please change the subject of your post making clear that you wanna open a folder in an external app.

Comment: And what does it have to do with a file? You wanna let open a folder in an external app. Its irrelevant if that folder contains files i think.

Comment: @blackapps What's wrong with my question? I said that when downloading a file, I create a folder and after downloading I want to open this folder. I use API > 28

Comment: @blackapps I am downloading a file and I know the path to this file. I am trying to create an intent to open this file in the file manager

Comment: "after downloading I want to open this folder" -- there is no `Intent` action to open a directory, sorry. And, even if there were, `Uri.fromFile()` has been more or less banned since Android 7.0.

Comment: @CommonsWare Okay, How do I write a method for opening this file folder?

Comment: There is no standard means of opening some sort of file manager on a directory, sorry.